# What do you call the fact of taking a personality test?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a noun that represents the fact of a user taking a personality test.

I was thinking about `examination`, but it sounds like education/certification.

*Context (unnecessary):

My website allows users to take personality tests.

It is a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) website, which means I have to use a noun for each type of data object.

The wording is quite important as it appears in the users' browser URL bar.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

> Analysis

or

> study
>   Assessment
>   Evaluation
>   Survey